# Websocket trigger from controller, session is null

Tags: spring-boot, websocket

I'm looking to trigger websocket from controller endpoint but always the session ends up to be null.

My connection is successful. But after I trigger endpoint both in controller and in websocket the session is null. Could someone please assist how I can sort this? Basically I want to have different session for different mobile app.
Hence session is important to me

Controller

```
@RestController
public class ClientController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ClientController.class);

    @Autowired
    private WebSocketServer webSocketServer;

    @Value("${ws.session.id}")
    private String sessionId;

        @RequestMapping(value = "/process", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public ResponseEntity<String> clientExample(@RequestBody String message) {
            logger.info("Inside clientExample method");
            //implement process client message here
            logger.info("Client request message: " + message);
            Session session = webSocketServer.getSessionById(sessionId);
        logger.info("session {}", session);
        webSocketServer.triggerOnMessage(message, session);
        return ResponseEntity.ok("WebSocket message triggered!");
    }
}
```

Websocket

```
@Component
@ServerEndpoint(value = "/websocket", configurator = WebSocketServer.HandshakeConfigurator.class)
public class WebSocketServer extends TextWebSocketHandler {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebSocketServer.class);
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    private static final Map<String, Session> sessionMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(String message, Session session) {
        logger.debug("Enter onMessage {} {}", message);
        try {
            Entry entry = objectMapper.readValue(message, Entry.class);
            String sessionId = (String) session.getUserProperties().get("sessionId");
            logger.debug("sessionId onMessage {}", sessionId);
            if (sessionId != null) {

                // Send the dynamic response back to the client
                session.getBasicRemote().sendText(message);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("There is an error in ws {}", e);
        }
    }



    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session) {
        // Store the session in the map using a unique identifier (e.g., session ID)
        String sessionId = (String) session.getUserProperties().get("sessionId");
        logger.debug("sessionId onOpen: {}", sessionId);
        if (sessionId != null) {
            sessionMap.put(sessionId, session);
        }
    }

    public Session getSessionById(String sessionId) {
        return sessionMap.get(sessionId);
    }

    @OnError
    public void onError(Throwable t) {
        logger.error("There is error in ws {}", t);
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session session, CloseReason reason) {
        logger.debug("Connection closed: {}", reason);
        String sessionId = (String) session.getUserProperties().get("sessionId");
        logger.debug("sessionId onClose {}", sessionId);
        if (sessionId != null) {
            sessionMap.remove(sessionId);
        }
    }

    public void triggerOnMessage(String message, Session session) {
        onMessage(message, session);
    }

    public static class HandshakeConfigurator extends ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator {
        @Override
        public void modifyHandshake(ServerEndpointConfig config, HandshakeRequest request, HandshakeResponse response) {
            // Get the session ID from the request (assuming the header key is "Session-ID")
            List<String> sessionIds = request.getHeaders().get("Session-ID");
            if (sessionIds != null && !sessionIds.isEmpty()) {
                String sessionId = sessionIds.get(0);
                config.getUserProperties().put("sessionId", sessionId);
            }
        }
    }
}
``

sessionId is coming from properties file
```